# userManager.FindById(userId) throws ArgumentNullException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I know this question has already been asked, but none of the answers seem to fit.

I have set up a standard asp.net MVC 5 web application using Individual Accounts.

I have not changed anything in the AccountController.
I just created a new Controller, and in the Index action method the two first lines are:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var user = userManager.FindById(userId);
```

I also declare an `ApplicationUserManager`:

```
private ApplicationUserManager userManager;
```

`userManager.FindById(userId)` throws the `ArgumentNullException`.

It all looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class WishlistController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db;
    private ApplicationUserManager userManager;

    // GET: Wishlist
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var user = userManager.FindById(userId); // This line throws the exception

        db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        return View(db.Wishlists.ToList().Where(wishlist => wishlist.User.Id == user.Id));
    }
```

**Edit**

Name of question changed since I discovered that `User.Identity.GetUserId()` does not return `null` anyway. It returns a nice long string as it should.

I still got the problem with `FindById(userId)`.

Comment: Does it return `null` or throw a `NullArgumentException`, you say both things?

Comment: GetUserId() returns null. FindById throws the exception.

Comment: At what point do you actually sign-in the user? If your code is executing during the same request that the user gets signed-in, then User.Identity will not be set yet. It's only set during the *next* request. (Similarly, when you call SignOut, it remains set until the end of the request).

Comment: When the user is signed it, it redirect to the HomeController Index. After that I go to the Wishlist Controller Index.

Comment: So, after your edits, I'm not sure what the symptoms are now. You now say that GetUserId() is returning a non-null string, but FindById(userId) throws ArgumentNullException?

Comment: Yes exactly. So that is actually the real problem.
I have had the problem for so much time now.

Comment: Where and how is your ApplicationUserManager instance created?

Comment: I have only done as you see in the question text.
Is there something I need?
I found another thread, not exactly like this, but the answer there was something about having a line in the Startup file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would *expect* the code you've posted (at your 4th revision) to fail at the line indicated, but I would expect it to raise a `NullReferenceException` rather than an `ArgumentNullException`. You're *declaring* an `ApplicationUserManager` variable, but not *initializing* it. So, when you attempt to call a method on it, that should fail.

I'm not sure why you want to retrieve the `User` object anyway. All you're doing with that `User` object is retrieving the user ID - which is exactly what you used to fetch the `User` in the first place. Why not just use the user ID directly? In which case, you don't even need the `ApplicationUserManager`.

Comment: Well, very good point. I did not see that.
I will try not using it right away.
As I explained Awais Mahmood, it actually throws a NullReferenceException if I try to get the user async.

Comment: But now it fails when trying to access the database by making a list. But that is a different question.

Comment: So this question can be closed? On your other problem, you should not do `ToList() ` before the `Where`. That will retrieve *all* the records from the database into memory, and *then* filter them. You want the filtering to happen on the server, so put the `ToList()` after the `Where`. Also, you should use a `using` statement when you create the `ApplicationDbContext` so that it gets properly disposed.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I will mark your question as answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling it into other controller then try

```
var t = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Since the way you are using is only valid in the controller directly hit by the view.

Comment: It still throws the exception.

Comment: if you try.. var t = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; does it return the username??

Comment: For some reason now, it returns both the Name (email) and the UserId.
But it still fails with the FindById method.
I edited the question so you can see how I declare the userManager.

Comment: whats the result of this: var t = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId)

Comment: It throws a `System.NullReferenceException`.
Now you write it with capital U.
Isn't it my own declared `ApplicationUserManagaer` I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

After successful sign in, `RedirectToAction("PostRegister")` with `[Authorize]` attribute and continue your logic. `PostRegister` is an action I created in `AccountController`. This solved my problem.